# Angular & Django File uploading : Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: django, angular, file-upload

I encounted the following problem : Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
I'm using Angular 8 to upload file and send it to django for some manipulations without saving the file and then return the pandas DataFrame as json.
Here is the Angular code:

```
uploadDatasetFile(formData : FormData){
    this._http.post(`${this.baseUrl}upload_dataset`, formData).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.dataFrame = data;
        console.log(data);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      } 
    );
  }
```

And the Django codes:

```
def upload_local_dataset(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Request FILES : ", request.FILES)
        dataset = pd.read_csv(request.FILES.get('datasetfilepath'), header=0, index_col=None)
        request.session['ts_dataset'] = dataset.to_json(orient='values')
        request.session['ts_dataset_copy'] = dataset.to_json(orient='values')

        return HttpResponse(dataset.to_json(orient='values'))
```

Thanks for your help. I'm new in Angular and Django, and I'm working on my internship project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the {% csrf_token %} in your form request

```
<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <anything_else>
</form>
```

Or you can add

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def upload_local_dataset(request):
    #stuff
```

to the post function.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/

Comment: Thanks! The second way it's good for me. I've seen it in a video tutorial but haven't known why the author used it.